# communication problem with laptop and workstation - turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, workstation, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having a problem with my workstation communicating with the turtlebot netbook.  from the netbook, I can run rviz or

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

and I will receive an image.  When I try the same from the workstation, I received no image.  In rviz it says no images received, in image_view a small white windows opens.  I believe I have set the ROS_MASTER_URI and the ROS_HOSTNAME correctly since I can publish from the workstation and subscribe from the laptop.  I can not subscribe from the workstation though, it doesn't say the topic isn't being published, all that it does is end the line in the terminal and has a blinking cursor on a blank line.  I ctrl C to stop the subscribing since nothing shows up.  Also, when I run :

```
rqt -s kobuki_dashboard
```

or this:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch
```

From the turtlebot netbook, it runs perfectly fine.  However, when I run it from the workstation the first one comes up but doesn't appear to be connected to the turtlebot. It says "Last message received 1372357558 seconds ago".  When I run the second command (rviz) it comes up with just a create base.  On the netbook It comes up correctly with the full turtlebot and kobuki base.  Any help is appreciated and if more information is needed just ask.  Thanks

Edit:
Also, running rxgraph from the workstation shows that none of the nodes are connected (they are all red circles)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66137/communication-problem-with-laptop-and-workstation---turtlebot/) by [mickey11592](https://answers.ros.org/users/5154/mickey11592/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2013-06-27**:
Can you tell us how did you set ROS_MASTER_URI and the ROS_HOSTNAME on the workstation and on the laptop ?
And have you synchronized workstation and laptop ? For this, you should use chrony: sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com or sudo ntpdate MasterIP. it may be the cause of "message received  seconds ago"

**Comment by [mickey11592](https://answers.ros.org/users/5154/mickey11592/) on 2013-06-28**:
I have already synchronized the workstation and laptop but I just resynchronized them using sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com.   The laptop ip is 192.168.1.4 the workstation ip is 192.168.1.3   on the workstation the ROS_MASTER_URI is http://192.168.1.4:11311  the ROS_HOSTNAME is 192.168.1.3.  The latptop

**Comment by [mickey11592](https://answers.ros.org/users/5154/mickey11592/) on 2013-06-28**:
ROS_HOSTNAME is 192.168.1.4 and the ROS_MASTER_URI is http://localhost:11311.  I did not set the ROS_MASTER_URI.  I setup the laptop according to the directions in the tutorial (under robots, turtlebot, network setup for the Live USB Installation, and the workstation according to the directions also

**Comment by [mickey11592](https://answers.ros.org/users/5154/mickey11592/) on 2013-06-28**:
I believe explicitly setting the ROS_MASTER_URI on the turtlebot fixed my problem.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your synchronization seems good and your IP configuration too. I cannot answer to your question, you should wait someone more experienced. I only can say you that for my part, I wrote explicitly ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.4:11311 on Turtlebot and added ROS_IP=192.168.1.4.

---

Originally posted by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) with karma: 411 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0